# webpage which should take C/C++ program from textarea

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and I have a challenge here:

I have to create a webpage which should take C/C++ program from textarea and should produce output of the program below the textarea using label when a button is clicked on the webpage.

I have no difficulty creating the front page(textarea,button,label or other controls) and reading the content of textarea in back end page(cs page).

But I don't have any idea how I can compile and run the program read from textarea and produce the output which can be assigned to a label on webpage.

Any help on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use

> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx

followed by

> Process.WaitForExit

to run the Visual C++ compiler (CL.EXE). The documentation for CL.EXE is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx

Your needs might be as simple as:

```
c:\path-to-compiler\cl.exe file.cpp /clr
```

In particular, I'd recommend that you review all your choices for the /clr option: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s(v=VS.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

You need to have Visual C++ on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you only want to treat single source file programs using only standard libraries. I also assume that you are working on Windows (asp.net). As soon as you have program source text, you can save it to a file. Then you start `cl` as an external program with your source as parameter to compile it. And finally you start the program you have just compiled. Of course, you will have to give pipes for Stdout and probably stdin and stderr.